# When Tamar offered evidence, was she acting as a witness?

Tags: halacha

In the trial of Tamar, she offers the items Judah left with her as security.  How were these objects offered into evidence?  Was Tamar acting as a witness?  Or were the objects and her possession of them just apparent without need for a witness to introduce them?  Or was some other legal principle at work.

Comment: Didn't she offer them after any trial? She's was on her way out to be burned היא מוצאת which is seemingly after any trials and deliberation.

Comment: You assume that Tamar's trial acted like post Matan-Tora Beis-Din. This assumption might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Tamar did not act as a witness nor did she offer the items to Yehuda as evidence. She sent the items to Yehuda for him to recognize them. She ensured that the messenger did not know what these items were. The medrash says that she sent the items by one messenger and the statement by another messenger. This was so that no one would know exactly what this meant.

She carefully did not submit the items in evidence, but wanted to leave it up to Yehuda to realize what had happened.

[Vayeishev 38:25](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8233/showrashi/true#v25)

> She was taken out, and she sent to her father in law, saying, "From
>   the man to whom these belong I am pregnant," and she said, "Please
>   recognize whose signet ring, cloak, and staff are these?"

**RASHI**

> and she sent to her father-in-law: She did not want to embarrass him
>   and say, “From you I am pregnant,” but, “From the man to whom these
>   belong.” She said, “If he confesses by himself, let him confess, and
>   if not, let them burn me, but I will not embarrass him.” From this
>   they (our Rabbis) said,“It is better for a person to be cast into a
>   fiery furnace than to embarrass his fellow in public.” [from Sotah
>   10b]